# Does a volatile value-only statement trigger a read access in C?

Tags: c, volatile

If I had the folowing declaration:

```
extern volatile int SOME_REGISTER;
```

and later on:

```
void trigger_read_register()
{
    SOME_REGISTER;
}
```

would calling `trigger_read_register()` issue a read request on `SOME_REGISTER` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the C11 spec, accessing a volatile is considered a side effect, and thus the compiler shouldn't optimize the (otherwise useless) access in your example.

So, the answer is that yes, it should read from memory.

See C11 standard (draft), section 5.1.2.3 section 2:

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or
>   calling a function that does any of those operations are all side
>   effects, which are changes in the state of the execution
>   environment. Evaluation of an expression in general includes both
>   value computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation
>   for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the
>   designated object.

Further, 4 says:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by
>   the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an
>   expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no
>   needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a
>   function or accessing a volatile object).

Comment: 'all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics'  sounds like a single expression statement still has to be evaluated, even if the result never goes anywhere.

Comment: Still in question if a read access is considered a side effect.

Comment: @dronus, what? "Accessing a volatile object...[is a] side effect" Seems pretty clear.

Comment: @dronus, as for your first comment, it says "An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced", so a single expression that never goes anywhere can be optimized out if it has no side effects.

Comment: Ok, it is more complex and it is not if or not to take the result of an expression, but if the expession may be considered to have any effect at all, which is true for any kind of access to expressions based on volatile locations, even if the result is not used.

Comment: There is an accepted  defect report about that. The implementations use the expected behaviour and the standard is missleading here.

Comment: @Olaf which is the expected behavior? Can you refer to the defect report?

Comment: @sinelaw: Pls search yourself. It definitively exists, I just lost the reference. It also says all compilers implement it the expected way (to perform the access).

Comment: @Olaf To me the standard seems to imply exactly that (to perform the access). What am I missing?

Comment: To serve the lazy: A simple google seaarch for "c defect report volatile" links to OpenStd, searching for "volatile" in the list: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_476

Comment: @Olaf so in this case, the code *is indeed* accessing a volatile object, and the defect has no implications

Comment: You did not get the point of defect reports. They are about "errors"/flaws in the standard, not the current implementations.

Comment: It seems the discussion DR 476  on http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_476 does in fact not care about side effects of reading volatile values, but on the correctness of the value. 

However, in my case the read access may have true sideeffects not neccessarely linked to the value of `SOME_REGISTER`. It is just the read access that trigger some side effects. This is used in many microcontrollers for example where some registers behave like post boxes and automatically clear some state (eg. a pending interrupt) if read.